# How to update state in child component with context value from parent (class components)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components

I know how to do it with functional components (unless I'm mistaken).

```
const [childComponentStateVar, setChildComponentStateVar] = useState()

useEffect(() => {

    setChildComponentStateVar(context.newDataFromParent)

}, [context.newDataFromParent])
```

In this example every time context.newDataFromParent changes, the state will get updated.

But I don't know the equivalent in class based components and I haven't been able to find it online. Any help?

My other question is, does it ever make sense to do this?

Comment: Something is wrong in the example `const [a, setA] = useEffect()`  do you mean `useState`?

Comment: yes useState, apologize for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In class components, you can do it with the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle function of the component.

```js
class Component extends React.Components {
  componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps) => {
    if (nextProps.data !== this.props.data) {
      this.props.setChildComponentStateVar(data)
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return ( <div /> );
  }
}
```

2. Hard to answer the question without any context of your use case

Comment: I appreciated it, so I see you're using props in this. But will it work the same for a context update?

Comment: Won't I need to use setState because I'd like to set the state in the child?